# How to connect MySQL running on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I have deployed my application on Google `gcloud` container engine. My application required `MySQL`. Application is running fine and connecting to `MySQL` correctly.
But I want to connect `MySQL` database from my local machine using `MySQL` Client (`Workbench`, or command line), Can some one help me how to expose this to local machine? and how can I open `MySQL` command line on `gcloud` shell ?

I have run below command but external ip is not there  :

```
$ kubectl get deployment
NAME        DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
app-mysql   1         1         1            1           2m
$ kubectl get pods
NAME                         READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
app-mysql-3323704556-nce3w   1/1       Running            0          2m
$ kubectl get service
NAME        CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP       PORT(S)    AGE
app-mysql   11.2.145.79   <none>            3306/TCP   23h
```

**EDIT**

I am using below `yml` file:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app-mysql
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app-mysql
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: data
        emptyDir: {}
      containers:
      - name: mysql
        image: mysql:5.6.22
        env:
        - name: MYSQL_USER
          value: root
        - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
          value: appdb
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data
          mountPath: /var/lib/mysql/
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app-mysql
spec:
  selector:
    app: app-mysql
  ports:
  - port: 3306
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try the `kubectl port-forward` command.

In your case; `kubectl port-forward app-mysql-3323704556-nce3w 3306:3306`

See [The documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_port-forward) for all available options.

Comment: i dont know if this is correct or not but its not working for me .. its showing below `Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:3306 -> 3306
Forwarding from [::1]:3306 -> 3306` and after that when i run `kubectl get services` its not showing external ip

Comment: You'll have to use the MySQL client on your local machine and connect to `localhost:3306`. This will use the tunnel that you created using `kubectl port-forward`.

Comment: its working fine now, i have reinstalled gcloud. Thanks For help

Comment: @Tim Slot I have the same case. I did all the above steps and it didn't work for me. Nothing is showing on my workbench at localhost.

Answer (score 6):

There are 2 steps involved:

1 ) You first perform port forwarding from localhost to your pod:

```
kubectl port-forward <your-mysql-pod-name> 3306:3306 -n <your-namespace>
```

2 ) Connect to database:

```
mysql -u root -h 127.0.0.1 -p <your-password>
```

Notice that you might need to change `127.0.0.1` to `localhost` - depends on your setup.

If host is set to:
`localhost` -  then a socket or pipe is used.
`127.0.0.1` -  then the client is forced to use TCP/IP.

You can check if your database is listening for TCP connections with `netstat -nlp`.

---

Read more in:

[Cant connect to local mysql server through socket tmp mysql sock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16325607/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-tmp-mysql-sock)

[Can not connect to server](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html)

Answer (score 2):

To add to the above answer, when you add **--address 0.0.0.0** kubectl should open 3306 port to the INTERNET too (not only localhost)!

`kubectl port-forward POD_NAME 3306:3306 --address 0.0.0.0`

Use it with caution for short debugging sessions only, on development systems at most. I used it in the following situation:

- colleague who uses Windows
- didn't have ssh key ready
- environment was a playground I was not afraid to expose to the world

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a service to your deployment. The service will add a load balancer with a public ip in front of your pod, so it can be accessed over the public internet.

See the documentation on [how to add a service to a Kubernetes deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/#creating-a-service). Use the following code to add a service to your app-mysql deployment:

```
kubectl expose deployment/app-mysql
```

You may also need to configure your MySQL service so it allows remote connections. See this link on [how to enable remote access on MySQL server](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html):

Comment: i dont think this might be correct way with kubernetes.

Comment: I updated the answer so it is more relevant to the question