# connect to local MySQL server

Tags: mysql, localhost

I am using MAC OS Sierra . and trying to access mysql but getting error like

```
UserXs-MacBook-Pro:~ Ayaz$ mysql -u root
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
UserXs-MacBook-Pro:~ Ayaz$
```

Comment: Can you check whether your MySQL instance is running or not firstly?

Comment: I have check its running via XAMP server

Comment: Can you try `mysql -u root -h 127.0.0.1` instead, /tmp/mysql.sock is used when connecting via localhost socket, whereas 127.0.0.1 will not use mysql.sock

Comment: `UserXs-MacBook-Pro:~ Ayaz$ mysql -u root -h 127.0.0.1
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61)
UserXs-MacBook-Pro:~ Ayaz$ `

Comment: Hi Ayaz, this will mean that you don't have a current instance of MySQL running to connect to.

Comment: I have mysql installed perfectly
`UserXs-MacBook-Pro:~ Ayaz$ mysql --version

mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.16, for osx10.12 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper`

Comment: MySQL is installed, but it is not running, try the following command `sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start`

Comment: `sh-3.2# sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start`
`sudo: /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server: command not found`

Comment: you should check this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16325607/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-tmp-mysql-sock/30359831#30359831

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have your MySQL UP and running, you could try the following step to get your issue sorted out!

This worked for me and hope works for you too!

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
```

This is an interesting [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16325607/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-tmp-mysql-sock) on SO which is on a similar discussion, hope that this helps!!!

Comment: i tried but got error like `sudo: /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server: command not found`

Comment: Did you check the question that I pointed to on the same topic?

Answer (score 0):

Check this. I wasn't running MySQL Server. Run server first.

```
$ mysql.server start
$ mysql -h localhost -u root -p your_password
```

if you install at Mac os. There is no password

```
$ mysql -h localhost -u root -p
```