# mysql returns socket error after failed login

Tags: mysql, sockets

I have been fighting against this error 

`ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)`

and somehow just reproduced it by simply failing to login properly.

```
$ mysql -u root
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

$ mysql -uroot
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

$ mysql -u root
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

What's going on here?

Comment: it looks like your MySQL server is not running... Did you check?

Comment: The server is definitely running. Unless failing to login to it crashed it?

Comment: Though it looks like it's still up.

Comment: Can you try passing a host parameter value in the mysql command like

`mysql -u root -h localhost` or 127.0.0.1

Comment: It looks like passing the host as 127.0.0.1 works
After shutting down mongod and rebooting it I get
```2017-02-18T06:07:37.988579Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2017-02-18T06:07:37.988604Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process using the same InnoDB data or log files.``` 
Do you know what's going on?

Comment: if using `localhost` host option does not work, then could be that the `127.0.0.1 localhost`  entry in your system's `hosts` file is missing, hence `localhost` is not being resolved correctly.

Comment: I already checked that and it's in my hosts file. Do you know about this data lock error? Getting it nonstop

Comment: then i'm mistaken, check this out this related so post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16325607/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-tmp-mysql-sock

Comment: I'm using OS X I don't have the service binary

Comment: How can I stop the mongod process in OS X ? Everything I try gives me this lock error

Comment: Can you try doing a `service mysql stop` and `service mysql start` and see if it helps. The idea is to make sure that there is only one MySQL server instance running in your machine for a particular config file.

Comment: anyway, i think it would be best if you create a separate SO post for that. :) Good luck!

Comment: Like I said, on OS X we don't have a service binary. `bash: service: command not found`