# ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through sock error on homebrew after MySQL 8.0

Tags: mysql, homebrew, mysql-8.0

I upgraded to MySQL 8.0 from 5.7 via homebrew, and found it is not working (maybe another reason might be I use Mojave Beta, but I'm not sure).

The `mysql` command gets me the following:

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>    '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

According to `brew mysql info`, I must launch it via `brew services start mysql`, so I started it (actually it was already running so I restarted), but nothing changed from the message above.

Also, `ps -xa | grep mysql` does not list anything but the grep itself.

So what is causing the launching error in my environment and how can I investigate this problem further?

---

#### Answer

Unfortunately, the user closed this question which is cleary related to version 8.0 upgrade and then guided me to the question that does not have the answer, so I cannot post my answer here, but if you hit the same wall, [check the answer I just wrote on the linked page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51316263/2360798).