# ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' . Error after installation

Tags: mysql

**Errors**

After running `service mysqld status` in Ubuntu 20.04, I get the error:

`Unit mysqld.service could not be found.`

And after running `sudo mysql` I get:

`ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)`.

**Info**

I've just installed MySQL with command

`sudo apt-get install mysql-server`.

There were no errors during installation. Reinstalling doesn't help. I've also tried to find problem in config files, but I don't have `/etc/my.cnf`. I am not sure, if it's ok.

`systemctl start mysql` does not help.

By the way, `service mysql status` works just alright and returns `active` status.

Comment: The file `my.cnf` is located in the directory `/etc/mysql` so it should be `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16325607/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-tmp-mysql-sock)

Answer (score 0):

Resolved question.

1. Delete `/usr/local/mysql`, `/usr/local/bin/mysql`, `/usr/bin/mysql`
2. Reinstall MySQL by

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install mysql-server`