# After shutting down MySQL with sudo mysqladmin shutdown it won't start again

Tags: mysql

I shut down my MySQL server with the following command - `sudo mysqladmin shutdown`. And now I want to start it again but it won't start. This is the error I get when I run `sudo mysqladmin start` command:

```
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock' exists!
```

I tried running `sudo mysqld start` but I get the following error:

```
2021-07-22 10:53:46 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2021-07-22 10:53:46 0 [Note] --secure-file-priv is set to NULL. Operations related to importing and exporting data are disabled
2021-07-22 10:53:46 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.6.47) starting as process 91078 ...
2021-07-22 10:53:46 91078 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
2021-07-22 10:53:46 91078 [ERROR] Fatal error: Please read "Security" section of the manual to find out how to run mysqld as root!

2021-07-22 10:53:46 91078 [ERROR] Aborting

2021-07-22 10:53:46 91078 [Note] Binlog end
2021-07-22 10:53:46 91078 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Btw I am running MySQL on my MacOS.

Comment: MySQL server is actually running? `service mysqld start`

Comment: @VeKe I tried but it gives me error as well, I updated my question with the error from  `sudo mysqld start`.

Comment: may be somewhere here you will find answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16325607/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-tmp-mysql-sock

Comment: Thanks you @VeKe! I was able to start the server.